# Error in Apache after installing SSL Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I tried installing an SSL certificate in Apache for XAMPP. After uploading the ssl certificates to the path: `C:\xampp\apache\ssl`, and editing the `httpd-ssl.conf` file and starting Apache, it wouldn't start. I have looked in the Apache Error Log and it had reported:

```
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.707470 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] AH02577: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file C:/xampp/apache/ssl/certificate.crt)
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.707470 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log for more information
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.707470 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key www.inti.ml:443:0, check C:/xampp/apache/ssl/certificate.crt
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.707470 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.708500 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.708500 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.708500 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=RSAPrivateKey)
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.708500 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.708500 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Tue Jul 28 09:16:49.708500 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2512:tid 704] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

I know that my Certificate files are NOT encrypted or password protected at all.

My VirtualHosts configuration file looks like this: (Replace mywebsite.com with my actual domain)

```
Listen 442

##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
#   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate,
#   and that httpd will negotiate as the client of a proxied server.
#   See the OpenSSL documentation for a complete list of ciphers, and
#   ensure these follow appropriate best practices for this deployment.
#   httpd 2.2.30, 2.4.13 and later force-disable aNULL, eNULL and EXP ciphers,
#   while OpenSSL disabled these by default in 0.9.8zf/1.0.0r/1.0.1m/1.0.2a.
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES

#  By the end of 2016, only TLSv1.2 ciphers should remain in use.
#  Older ciphers should be disallowed as soon as possible, while the
#  kRSA ciphers do not offer forward secrecy.  These changes inhibit
#  older clients (such as IE6 SP2 or IE8 on Windows XP, or other legacy
#  non-browser tooling) from successfully connecting.  
#
#  To restrict mod_ssl to use only TLSv1.2 ciphers, and disable
#  those protocols which do not support forward secrecy, replace
#  the SSLCipherSuite and SSLProxyCipherSuite directives above with
#  the following two directives, as soon as practical.
# SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA
# SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA

#   User agents such as web browsers are not configured for the user's
#   own preference of either security or performance, therefore this
#   must be the prerogative of the web server administrator who manages
#   cpu load versus confidentiality, so enforce the server's cipher order.
SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

#   SSL Protocol support:
#   List the protocol versions which clients are allowed to connect with.
#   Disable SSLv3 by default (cf. RFC 7525 3.1.1).  TLSv1 (1.0) should be
#   disabled as quickly as practical.  By the end of 2016, only the TLSv1.2
#   protocol or later should remain in use.
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is an internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
#SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   OCSP Stapling (requires OpenSSL 0.9.8h or later)
#
#   This feature is disabled by default and requires at least
#   the two directives SSLUseStapling and SSLStaplingCache.
#   Refer to the documentation on OCSP Stapling in the SSL/TLS
#   How-To for more information.
#
#   Enable stapling for all SSL-enabled servers:
#SSLUseStapling On

#   Define a relatively small cache for OCSP Stapling using
#   the same mechanism that is used for the SSL session cache
#   above.  If stapling is used with more than a few certificates,
#   the size may need to be increased.  (AH01929 will be logged.)
#SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"

#   Seconds before valid OCSP responses are expired from the cache
#SSLStaplingStandardCacheTimeout 3600

#   Seconds before invalid OCSP responses are expired from the cache
#SSLStaplingErrorCacheTimeout 600

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:442>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName www.mywebsite.com
ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   Server Certificate:
#   Point SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
#   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
#   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
#   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
#   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
#   ciphers, etc.)
#   Some ECC cipher suites (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt)
#   require an ECC certificate which can also be configured in
#   parallel.
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
#   ECC keys, when in use, can also be configured in parallel
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\xampp\apache\ssl\certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\xampp\apache\ssl\private.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
#   certificate for convenience.
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\xampp\apache\ssl\ca_bundle.crt"

#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCACertificatePath "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crt"
#SSLCACertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"

#   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
#   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
#   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
#   of them (file must be PEM encoded).
#   The CRL checking mode needs to be configured explicitly
#   through SSLCARevocationCheck (defaults to "none" otherwise).
#   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCARevocationPath "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crl"
#SSLCARevocationFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl"
#SSLCARevocationCheck chain

#   Client Authentication (Type):
#   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
#   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
#   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
#   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#   TLS-SRP mutual authentication:
#   Enable TLS-SRP and set the path to the OpenSSL SRP verifier
#   file (containing login information for SRP user accounts). 
#   Requires OpenSSL 1.0.1 or newer. See the mod_ssl FAQ for
#   detailed instructions on creating this file. Example:
#   "openssl srp -srpvfile ${SRVROOT}/conf/passwd.srpv -add username"
#SSLSRPVerifierFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/passwd.srpv"

#   Access Control:
#   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
#   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
#   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
#   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
#   for more details.
#<Location />
#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
#            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
#            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
#           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
#</Location>

#   SSL Engine Options:
#   Set various options for the SSL engine.
#   o FakeBasicAuth:
#     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
#     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
#     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
#     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
#     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
#   o ExportCertData:
#     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
#     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
#     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
#     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
#     into CGI scripts.
#   o StdEnvVars:
#     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
#     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
#     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
#     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
#     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
#   o StrictRequire:
#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
#     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
#     and no other module can change it.
#   o OptRenegotiate:
#     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
#     directives are used in per-directory context. 
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
#   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
#   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
#   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
#   approach you can use one of the following variables:
#   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
#     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
#     SSL close notify alert is sent or allowed to be received.  This violates
#     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
#     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
#   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
#     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
#     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
#     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
#     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
#     works correctly. 
#   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
#   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
#   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
#   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
#   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
#   "force-response-1.0" for this.
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

I am currently using a SSL certificate issued by OpenSSL.
I know it is not a port issue because i've already replaced the port many times and found no problem with it.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: The first and third lines of your log error shows everything. The file that you are giving to Apache is an encrypted key (or some other garbage, because using a filename `certificate.crt` for a keyfile is technically possible but bound to create confusion) and `SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin` that you use is not supported on your platform, hence your setup is impossible. You have to decrypt the key or find another option for `SSLPassPhraseDialog`.  Also your question would be more on topic on [sf] or [su] than here as it is not related to programming.

Comment: PS: when giving data, from your configuration file, you can remove everything starting with `#`  they are comments and hence won't help at all (and you have many of them making everything hard to read). Also since your problem is related to only a specific module, you could display only the `SSL` directives, the rest is irrelevant for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your port 442 really intended? Should be 443.